# How to convert CGImage to OTVideoFrame

Tags: ios, opentok

What is the best way to convert CGImage to OTVideoFrame?

I tried to get the underlying CGImage pixel buffer and feed it into an OTVideoBuffer, but got a distorted image.

Here is what I have done:

1. created a new OTVideoFormat object with ARGB pixel format
2. Set the bytesPerRow of the OTVideoFormat to height*width*4. Taking the value of CGImageGetBytesPerRow(...) did not work, got no error messages but also no frames on the other end of the line.
3. Copied the rows truncating them to convert from  CGImageGetBytesPerRow(...) to height*width*4 bytes per row.
4. Got a distorted image with rows slightly shifted

Here is the code:

```
func toOTVideoFrame() throws -> OTVideoFrame {
    let width : UInt32 = UInt32(CGImageGetWidth(self)) // self is a CGImage
    let height : UInt32 = UInt32(CGImageGetHeight(self))
    assert(CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(self) == 32)
    assert(CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self) == 8)
    let bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self)
    assert(bitmapInfo.contains(CGBitmapInfo.FloatComponents) == false)
    assert(bitmapInfo.contains(CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrderDefault))
    assert(CGImageGetAlphaInfo(self) == .NoneSkipFirst) 

    let bytesPerPixel : UInt32 = 4
    let cgImageBytesPerRow : UInt32 = UInt32(CGImageGetBytesPerRow(self))
    let otFrameBytesPerRow : UInt32 = bytesPerPixel * width

    let videoFormat = OTVideoFormat()
    videoFormat.pixelFormat = .ARGB
    videoFormat.bytesPerRow.addObject(NSNumber(unsignedInt: otFrameBytesPerRow))
    videoFormat.imageWidth = width
    videoFormat.imageHeight = height
    videoFormat.estimatedFramesPerSecond = 15
    videoFormat.estimatedCaptureDelay = 100

    let videoFrame = OTVideoFrame(format: videoFormat)
    videoFrame.timestamp = CMTimeMake(0, 1) // This is temporary
    videoFrame.orientation = OTVideoOrientation.Up // This is temporary

    let dataProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(self)
    let imageData  : NSData = CGDataProviderCopyData(dataProvider)!

    let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(Int(otFrameBytesPerRow * height)) 

    for currentRow in 0..<height {
        let currentRowStartOffsetCGImage = currentRow * cgImageBytesPerRow
        let currentRowStartOffsetOTVideoFrame = currentRow * otFrameBytesPerRow
        let cgImageRange = NSRange(location: Int(currentRowStartOffsetCGImage), length: Int(otFrameBytesPerRow))
        imageData.getBytes(buffer.advancedBy(Int(currentRowStartOffsetOTVideoFrame)),
            range: cgImageRange)
    }

    do {
        let planes = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>>.alloc(1)
        planes.initialize(buffer)
        videoFrame.setPlanesWithPointers(planes, numPlanes: 1)
        planes.dealloc(1)
    }

    return videoFrame
}
```

The result image:

[image: The distorted resulting image]

Answer (score 2):

Solved this issue by my own.

It appears to be a bug in the OpenTok SDK. The SDK does not seem to be able to handle images whose size is not a multiple of 16. When I changed all image sizes to be multiple of 16, everything started to work fine.

TokBox did not bother to state this limitation in the API documentation, nor throw an exception when the input image size is not a multiple of 16.

This is a second critical bug I have found in OpenTok SDK. I strongly suggest you do not use this product. It is of very low quality.